# Where did lxml's Element.getAttribute() method call go?

Tags: python, lxml

I've been diggin' and diggin' about 2 hours but I couldn't find a reason for this error:

```
1) JBoss
2) Tomcat
Select an application: 1
<App id="1" type="JBoss" path="" state="ok"/>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/RService.py", line 47, in <module>
    Stats = app.getAttribute('state')
AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._Element' object has no attribute 'getAttribute'
```

And part of my code is:

```
    app_types = set(nXML.xpath('//Group[@id=$gList]//descendant::App/@type',gList=gList))
    app_dict = dict((x+1,y) for (x,y) in enumerate(app_types))

    print "\n".join("%d) %s" % x for x in sorted(app_dict.items()))
    app_selection = input("Select an application: ")
    app_type = app_dict.get(int(app_selection))

    for app in nXML.xpath('//Group[@id=$gList]//App[@type=$app_type]',gList=gList,app_type=app_type):
        print etree.tostring(app)

        Stats = app.getAttribute('state')
        stype = app.getAttribute('type')
        trigger = 0

        while trigger < 1:
            if Stats == 'ok':
                try: ... ...
```

It was working before, what happened to the syntax?

Thanks

Comment: There is no mention of this method in the current documentation. Did you upgrade from an ancient version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try app.get('state') instead. That works for me with LXML 2.2.7.

Comment: Its all good but I can't print parentNode attribute? Like this: `print app.parentNode.get('state')` Error: `AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._Element' object has no attribute 'parentNode'`

Comment: It's app.getparent(). The LXML Element is documented at http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html . It has all the methods.